# Execute a script once on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was messing about with some code but I am struggling a little bit to achieve what I want. In the example here I have a map which displays when there are coordinates in my fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/xJhmk/9/

```
// Generic Map Display
function mapDisplay() {

        var latval = $('#lat').val(),
            lngval = $('#lng').val();
        if ($.trim(latval) != '' && $.trim(lngval) != '') {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
            $('#map_canvas').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#map_canvas').addClass('hidden');
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is have this execute once per page, so that if there are values in the fields when the page loads then the map displays, but if the values get deleted after the page load or changes, the map will not change, since it read the variables at the start of ther page load only.

Can someone show me on my jsfiddle how that might be displayed please?

Comment: That all depends on your definition of page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the function `mapDisplay();`, on document ready call `mapDisplay`

```
jQuery(function($){
    mapDisplay();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dxLkg/)

Comment: But I only want to call it once on page load, without needing a button to load it or have it keep pulling the revised variables (if they happen to change over the course of the user being on the page)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){

mapDisplay();

}
```

This runs your code on the onload event

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to have it in jquery?

Comment: i'll leave as is for future refernce seeing the other answers give jQuery examples

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(function()
{
    mapDisplay();
}  

// Generic Map Display
function mapDisplay() {

    var latval = $('#lat').val(),
        lngval = $('#lng').val();
    if ($.trim(latval) != '' && $.trim(lngval) != '') {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latval, lngval),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        $('#map_canvas').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#map_canvas').addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

You declare a function, and after page is loaded (the $(function() {} ), it is executed.